# Column is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to tables:
`DeviceInstace` and `Device`

They are connected with `Foreign Key` on `DeviceInstance.DeviceId=Device.Id`

I have SQL query:

```
select d.CatalogNo,d.Manufacturer,d.Name, sum(quantity) 
from DeviceInstance di 
full join Device d 
on d.Id=di.DeviceId 
group by di.DeviceId
```

with which I need to make little summary that consist of:

- catalog number
- manufacturer
- device name
- number of devices (sum of values in quntity columns for these deviceIds)

But I'm facing some `Grouping by` issuses.

All I try refuse me error like this one:

```
Column 'Device.CatalogNo' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

I know I can group by `CatalogNo` but then ten sum of quantity will return wrong numbers.

Can anyone suggest me how to repair it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just modify GROUP BY clause:

```
group by d.DeviceId, d.CatalogNo,d.Manufacturer,d.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to Add d.CatalogNo,d.Manufacturer in Group By Clause

Try this

```
select d.CatalogNo,d.Manufacturer,d.Name, sum(quantity) 
from DeviceInstance di 
full join Device d 
on d.Id=di.DeviceId 
group by d.Name, d.CatalogNo,d.Manufacturer
```